# How to query with has many associations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Could someone help me with my query? I have the following associations:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :customer_subscriptions, dependent: :destroy
end

class CustomerSubscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

I am trying to get the customer whose all customer subscription status is active. Here, customer subscription has status active,canceled and deleted. I am trying to use the where query insted of select query.

Comment: Have you tried `joins`, and why do you specifically need to use `where` query?

Comment: For what you're trying to achieve. You can join the customer subscription and find the active customer subscriptions `Customer.joins(:customer_subscriptions).where(customer_subscriptions: {status: :active}).where.not(customer_subscriptions: {status: [:canceled, :deleted]})`. NB: This is not tested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a technique which uses a single query that returns customers for which at least one active subscription exists, and no non-active subscriptions exist.

```
Customer.
  where(
    CustomerSubscription.
      where(status: 'active').
      where(
        CustomerSubscription.
          arel_table[:customer_id].
          eq(Customer.arel_table[:id])
      ).arel.exists).
  where.not(
    CustomerSubscription.
      where.not(status: 'active').
      where(
        CustomerSubscription.
          arel_table[:customer_id].
          eq(Customer.arel_table[:id])
      ).arel.exists)
```

I might have lost track of the parentheses there, mind. It can definitely be tidied up with scopes, so it looks more:

```
Customer.has_an_active_subscription.has_no_nonactive_subscriptions
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
customer_ids_with_non_active_subscriptions = 
  CustomerSubscription.select(:customer_id).where.not(status: 'active')
Customer
  .joins(:customer_subscriptions)
  .where.not(customers: { id: customer_ids_with_non_active_subscriptions })
```

Explanation:

- First, determine the list of customers' ids that have at least one
  non-active subscription.
- Then load all customers that have at least
  one subscription (the `joins` part) but exclude those customers who are on the first list.

Answer (score 0):

Get all the customer subscriptions that have active status then map on each one to get the customer

```
CustomerSubscription.where(status: 'active').map { |cs| cs.customer}
```

Comment: This will find customers that have at least one active subscription but there might be other subscriptions associated with the same customers that are not active. But the OP wants to load only those customers whose subscriptions are all active. Imagine a customer having two subscriptions, one is active the other is not active. That customer should not be on the list.